# Compiling a C++ program with all libs it needs

Tags: c++, openmp, eclipse-cdt

When I compile C++ code that uses **openmp** libs with *visual studio*, the program is very portable - because it runs in other machines with Windows without problems.

When I compile the C++ code with *Eclipse CDT* (oxygen and g++ cygwin) for Windows, in general, I need to install the correct runtime libs in the other machines to be able to run the program. I don't find it practical.

Based on this:

1) What is the right way to compile the code including all libs (g++ and openmp) to run in another Windows system?

2) How can do this in Eclipse CDT for Windows?

Comment: The problem is most windows users will not have the cygwin binaries installed. You can package these in your installer. Although this would be the same for a Visual Studio 2015+ application on an older windows operating system. I package the appropriate Visual Studio runtime in my installer in every application I produce at work.

Comment: I think the difference is static vs. dynamic linking. Is there a difference in size between the two versions? You can either static link a library. Then it is linked into your executable and your executable contains it. Or you can dynamic link it. Then your executable is smaller but it need the library.

Comment: I guessed the difference was Windows 10 has the runtime for VS2015+ in the OS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in compiling, but in distributing. Windows and windows toolchains intend to use dynamic linking. Now, if created software are dependent on particular version of runtime, which includes side-by-side build, they can be run only if exactly that build is installed. Several builds of same library version may exist, they are fetched using side-by-side (SxS) mechanics.

On Linux platform this problem is solved through package manager and dependencies. On Windows you have to create an installer, which would contain or have ability to download proper version of libraries. Also installer may do proper changes to OS settings, and register them , for future rollback.

Note, that runtime libraries have debug variants which cannot be distributed and debug build of software must be run on developer system only.

"Portable" apps that appear here and there and can be run without installation, have special status not to be dependant on SxS run-time library. To my knowledge cygwin and mingw32 allowed to create such, the 64bit project of mingw had problems with that.  But they are still dependant on particular versions of system .dll and may break or malfunction in case of mismatch.

Even in that case you still need some .dll, from mingw, cygwin, Qt, whatever you use and  what is not a part of OS, to place them where program can reach them. Which can be folder comtaining the executable. Static linking became a gimmick of past for desktops, because of code bloat - dynamic library size easily can be dozens of megabytes.

And last: you don't compile anything  with Visual Studio or with Eclipse CDT. Both designed to use various compilers, it's juse environments. You have to specify normal;y, what compiler your IDE uses, not what IDE you use to run ot.